# Module 'swagger_client' has no attribute 'CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi'

Tags: python, swagger, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

I'm using Microsoft's official GitHub repository to set up [Azure Speech Services Batch Transcription API from Python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/python)

I receive an error from line number 142 in main.py which states

```
AttributeError: module 'swagger_client' has no attribute 'CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi'
```

I  suppose this has to do with the recent changes made to the swagger_client. How to fix this issue any thoughts?

I already followed the below threads and noticed a few others also reported the same issue but nothing helped,
[Thread 1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/477), [Thread 2](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/50995)

To debug I gave `print(dir(swagger_client))` before it throws the above error and here is the output of the print statement

```
['ApiClient', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30DatasetsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30EndpointsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30EvaluationsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30ModelsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30ProjectsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'ApiSpeechtotextV30TranscriptionsLocalesGet200ApplicationJsonResponse', 'Component', 'Configuration', 'Dataset', 'DatasetProperties', 'DatasetUpdate', 'DefaultApi', 'Endpoint', 'EndpointLinks', 'EndpointProperties', 'EndpointPropertiesUpdate', 'EndpointUpdate', 'EntityError', 'EntityReference', 'Error', 'ErrorContent', 'ErrorDetail', 'Evaluation', 'EvaluationProperties', 'EvaluationUpdate', 'File', 'FileLinks', 'FileProperties', 'HealthStatus', 'InnerError', 'InnerErrorV2', 'InternalModel', 'Links', 'ManagementModel', 'ManagementModelArray', 'ManagementModelProperties', 'Model', 'ModelCopy', 'ModelDeprecationDates', 'ModelFile', 'ModelLinks', 'ModelManifest', 'ModelProperties', 'ModelUpdate', 'PaginatedDatasets', 'PaginatedEndpoints', 'PaginatedEvaluations', 'PaginatedFiles', 'PaginatedModels', 'PaginatedProjects', 'PaginatedTranscriptions', 'PaginatedWebHooks', 'Project', 'ProjectLinks', 'ProjectProperties', 'ProjectUpdate', 'Transcription', 'TranscriptionProperties', 'TranscriptionUpdate', 'WebHook', 'WebHookEvents', 'WebHookEvents1', 'WebHookLinks', 'WebHookProperties', 'WebHookPropertiesUpdate', 'WebHookUpdate', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'absolute_import', 'api', 'api_client', 'configuration', 'models', 'rest']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: module 'swagger_client' has no attribute 'CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi

The above error states you have not correctly installed **`swagger_client`**.

Make sure you have downloaded the API client library with Swagger correctly and the Python environment using pip to install the python-client module: `pip install path/to/package/python-client`

I followed the same [Github-document](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/batch/python) with the same code can able to get the transcription from the audio file.

I also checked with **`print(dir(swagger_client)`** i can able to get the **`CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi`** attribute and my version **`swagger_client = 1.0.0`**.

[image]

**Code:**

```
def transcribe():
    logging.info("Starting transcription client...")

    # configure API key authorization: subscription_key
    configuration = swagger_client.Configuration()
    configuration.api_key["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = SUBSCRIPTION_KEY
    configuration.host = f"https://{SERVICE_REGION}.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/speechtotext/v3.1"

    # create the client object and authenticate
    client = swagger_client.ApiClient(configuration)

    # create an instance of the transcription api class
    api = swagger_client.CustomSpeechTranscriptionsApi(api_client=client)
    properties = swagger_client.TranscriptionProperties()
    transcription_definition = transcribe_from_single_blob(RECORDINGS_BLOB_URI, properties)
    created_transcription, status, headers = api.transcriptions_create_with_http_info(transcription=transcription_definition)

    transcription_id = headers["location"].split("/")[-1]

    # Log information about the created transcription. If you should ask for support, please
    # include this information.
    logging.info(f"Created new transcription with id '{transcription_id}' in region {SERVICE_REGION}")

    logging.info("Checking status.")

    completed = False

    while not completed:
        # wait for 5 seconds before refreshing the transcription status
        time.sleep(5)

        transcription = api.transcriptions_get(transcription_id)
        logging.info(f"Transcriptions status: {transcription.status}")

        if transcription.status in ("Failed", "Succeeded"):
            completed = True

        if transcription.status == "Succeeded":
            pag_files = api.transcriptions_list_files(transcription_id)
            for file_data in _paginate(api, pag_files):
                if file_data.kind != "Transcription":
                    continue

                audiofilename = file_data.name
                results_url = file_data.links.content_url
                results = requests.get(results_url)
                logging.info(f"Results for {audiofilename}:\n{results.content.decode('utf-8')}")
        elif transcription.status == "Failed":
            logging.info(f"Transcription failed: {transcription.properties.error.message}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    transcribe()
```

**Output:**

```
05/08/2023 11:10:07 AM India Standard Time Starting transcription client...
05/08/2023 11:10:08 AM India Standard Time Created new transcription with id 'your id' in region <region>05/08/2023 11:10:08 AM India Standard Time Checking status.
05/08/2023 11:10:13 AM India Standard Time Transcriptions status: Running
05/08/2023 11:10:19 AM India Standard Time Transcriptions status: Succeeded
05/08/2023 11:10:20 AM India Standard Time Results for contenturl_0.json:
{
  "source": "https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/test/harvard.wav?<sas-token>",
  "timestamp": "2023-05-08T05:40:15Z",
  "durationInTicks": 183500000,
  "duration": "PT18.35S",
  "combinedRecognizedPhrases": [
    {
      "channel": 0,
      "lexical": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "itn": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "maskedITN": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "display": "The stale smell of old beer lingers. It takes heat to bring out the odor. A cold dip restores health and zest. A salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos. Al pastor are my favorite. A zestful food is the hot cross bun."
    },
    {
      "channel": 1,
      "lexical": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "itn": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "maskedITN": "the stale smell of old beer lingers it takes heat to bring out the odor a cold dip restores health and zest a salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos al pastor are my favorite a zestful food is the hot cross bun",
      "display": "The stale smell of old beer lingers. It takes heat to bring out the odor. A cold dip restores health and zest. A salt pickle tastes fine with ham tacos. Al pastor are my favorite. A zestful food is the hot cross bun
```

[image]